# update or remove custom font-family

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I created 2 fonts using

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'test1';
     src: URL('NBSBold.ttf') format ('ttf');
     font-family: 'test2';
     src: URL('NBSMedium.ttf') format ('ttf');

}
```

I am wanting to change the names of these now, however when i just change the names in the above code it doesn't register them being changed. How can I change these names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change them
2. Press save
3. Open browser with your webpage
4. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>

(Usually previous Styling sheets are cached in the browser, you have to refresh it for it to show.)

Or, there is another line in the Style sheet similar to this :

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
```

Which overrides the font-family change.

Comment: Then what do you mean with "It doesn't register them being changed"? If you change it in your code, there is no way it is keeping its old font.

Comment: There obviously is a way cos its happening to me

Comment: Look at your whole CSS, there might be a line where you have `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;` or something similar to this. If it isn't this, then you have a ghost in your computer, and you should call the police asap.